# MySQL view subquery with custom where clause?

Tags: mysql, view, subquery

I am trying to design a view on a MySQL database that stores information about football (soccer).

My goal is to create a view that returns all the goals and the basic information of the scorers. This is a simplified version of what the view used to look like:

```
SELECT P.Name AS Player,
       P.TeamName AS Team,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Goals G
        WHERE G.Scorer = P.playerID) AS TotalGoals
FROM Players P
```

So far, everything's right. The problem started when I wanted to count goals only within a certain season, specified in the `WHERE` clause, as I show below:

```
SELECT * FROM GoalsView WHERE Season = 1
```

And for it to return automatically only the count of the goals of the season in `WHERE` clause, as if the subquery was automatically edited to make it look like:

```
[...]
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Goals G
WHERE G.Scorer = P.playerID
AND Season=1) AS TotalGoals
[...]
```

I hope I made myself clear. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is

```
SELECT P.Name AS Player,
   P.TeamName AS Team,
   (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Goals G
    WHERE G.Scorer = P.playerID AND season=1 GROUP By season) AS TotalGoals
 FROM Players P
```

I don't know whether you have separate table for season or a column

Answer (score 0):

In order to have access to goals.season, you must join the two tables:

```
select 
  p.name as player,
  p.teamname as team,
  count(goals.id) as totalgoals
from players p
left join goals g on g.scorer = p.playerid
group by p.name, p.teamname;
```